# Amend list from file - Correct syntax and file format?

Tags: python

I currently have a list hard coded into my python code.  As it keeps expanding, I wanted to make it more dynamic by reading the list from a file.  I have read through many articles about how to do this, but in practice I can't get this working. So firstly, here is an example of the existing hardcoded list:

```
serverlist = []
serverlist.append(("abc.com", "abc"))
serverlist.append(("def.com", "def"))
serverlist.append(("hji.com", "hji"))
```

When I enter the command 'print serverlist' the output is shown below and my list works perfectly when I access it:

```
[('abc.com', 'abc'), ('def.com', 'def'), ('hji.com', 'hji')]
```

Now I've replaced the above code with the following:

```
serverlist = []
with open('/server.list', 'r') as f:
    serverlist = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
```

With the contents of server.list being:

```
'abc.com', 'abc'
'def.com', 'def'
'hji.com', 'hji'
```

When I now enter the command `print serverlist`, the output is shown below:

```
["'abc.com', 'abc'", "'def.com', 'def'", "'hji.com', 'hji'"]
```

And the list is not working correctly.  So what exactly am I doing wrong?  Am I reading the file incorrectly or am I formatting the file incorrectly? Or something else?

Comment: It's good practice to accept an answer

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the file are not interpreted as Python code. When you read a `line in f`, it is a string; and the quotation marks, commas etc. in your file are just those characters as parts of a string.

If you want to create some other data structure from the string, you need to *parse* it. The program has no way to know that you want to turn the string `"'abc.com', 'abc'"` into the tuple `('abc.com', 'abc')`, unless you instruct it to.

This is the point where the question becomes "too broad".

If you are in control of the file contents, then you can simplify the data format to make this more straightforward. For example, if you just have `abc.com abc` on the line of the file, so that your string ends up as `'abc.com abc'`, you can then just `.split()` that; this assumes that you don't need to represent whitespace inside either of the two items. You could instead split on another character (like the comma, in your case) if necessary (`.split(',')`). If you need a general-purpose hammer, you might want to look into JSON. There is also `ast.literal_eval` which can be used to treat text as simple Python literal expressions - in this case, you would need the lines of the file to include the enclosing parentheses as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to let go of the quotes in your file and rewrite it as

```
abc.com, abc
def.com, def
hji.com, hji
```

the code to load can  be reduced to a one liner using the fact that files are iterables

```
with open('servers.list') as f:
    servers = [tuple(line.split(', ')) for line in f]
```

Remember that using a file as an iterator already strips off the newlines.

You can allow arbitrary whitespace by doing something like

```
servers = [tuple(word.strip() for word in line.split(',')) for line in f]
```

It might be easier to use something like regex to parse the original format. You could use an expression that captures the parts of the line you care about and matches but discards the rest:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('\'(.+)\',\\s*\'(.+)\'')
```

You could then extract the names from the matched groups

```
with open('servers.list') as f:
    servers = [pattern.fullmatch(line).groups() for line in f]
```

This is just a trivialized example. You can make it as complicated as you wish for your real file format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
serverlist = []

with open('/server.list', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        serverlist.append(tuple(line.rstrip('\n').split(',')))
```

**Explanation**

- You want an explicit `for` loop so you cycle through each line as expected.
- You need `list.append` for each line to append to your list.
- You need to use `split(',')` in order to split by commas.
- Convert to `tuple` as this is your desired output.

**List comprehension method**

The `for` loop can be condensed as below:

```
with open('/server.list', 'r') as f:
    serverlist = [tuple(line.rstrip('\n').split(',')) for line in f]
```

Comment: the split should not act on whitespaces but on commas : `split(',')`

Comment: You don't need an explicit for loop but this should work fine